# redux-saga api call response filtering

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I' trying to filter my redux-saga generator functions api response like this.

```
    function* loadSingleDataAsync(id) {
  console.log('Second Saga Works');
  let wholeData = [];
  let singleData = [];
  agent
    .get(
      `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=xxx`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      wholeData = [...res.body.data];
      singleData = wholeData.filter((currencie) => currencie.id === id);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('--------err', err);
    });
  yield delay(700);
  yield put({ type: 'RECEIVE_SINGLE_API_DATA_ASYNC', singleData });
}
```

After this I'm calling it this way:

```
 export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([takeEvery('RECEIVE_API_DATA', loadDataAsync), takeEvery('RECEIVE_SINGLE_API_DATA', loadSingleDataAsync)]);
}
```

The first function is working but the second don't,Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a try, catch inside the saga helps you to know if the saga chain is broken because of any empty responses or data issues.